# Is there any difference between passing variables into function and import them by USE?

Tags: php, function, parameter-passing

Take a look at this code:

```
$str = implode(', ', array_map(function($var1) use ($var2) { /* code */ }, $arr));
```

As you see I've used `USE` keyword to import `var2` in the function. Ok all fine. Just I can do that without `USE` either. Something like this:

```
$str = implode(', ', array_map(function($var1. $var2) { /* code */ }, $arr));
```

So when should I use `USE` ? Has it any specific advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to use `use` is to set the variable value at the time of function definition rather than when the function is called. For example,

```
$var1 = 1;
$var2 = 2;
$fun1 = function($var1) use ($var2) { return $var1 + $var2; };
$fun2 = function($var1, $var2) { return $var1 + $var2; };

echo $fun1(3);
// prints 5
echo $fun2(3,4);
// prints 7
```

Answer (score 3):

`use` with functions is needed to pass variables from one scope to another. Useful when working with anonymous functions which do not have access to variables outside their scope (parent scope). See example #3 in the link below.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

As for your example, I'm guessing you would/should have been getting missing argument warning messages when using 2 arguments inside your anonymous function. Your second example would basically look something like this:

```
function myFunction($var1, $var2)
{
    // myFunction logic
}
$arr = array('string1', 'string2', 'string3');
$temp = array();
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $temp[] = myFunction($value); // produces an e_warning since myFunction expects 2 arguments
}
$str = implode(', ', $temp);
```